# What is the motivation for using variables in closures formats? var foo: ((String) -> Void)?

Tags: swift, closures

I have recently seen some code in Swift with these statements `var foo: ((String) -> Void)`. I was able to understand how closures work, but I would like to understand why in some cases we have to use:

```
didTap?(...)
```

I know we are declaring it as optional and every attribute in Swift must have an initializer, I could also understand trailing closures too.
But what is the advantage of doing this, what can it give us?

```
import UIKit

class FooTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var swiftLang = ["Swift", "release date - 2014", "WWDC"]
    
    var didTap: ((String) -> Void)?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        #if DEBUG
        print("Hello TableView")
        #endif
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return swiftLang.count > 0 ? swiftLang.count : 0 
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = swiftLang[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        didTap?(swiftLang[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, a closure is just an anonymous function, i.e. one not necessarily declared. Thus, in most aspects, they truly act the same way, with different semantics. A difference, for example, is that in a Function, the arguments are referenced by name, whereas in a closure, they are not.

This can be taken a step further. I can declare the variable `didTap` and initialize it in another viewcontroller, whereas that is a bit more difficult to do as a function.

```
class 1:
Class2.didTap = {} //anonymous function declared in class 2 but given a value in class 1
```

This then gets into the Protocol portion of Swift which allows you to

1. Define a protocol
2. Create a reference to the protocol in class A
3. Extend the protocol in class B
4. And now you can use the functionality from class B within the reference of your class A. Which is the basis of communication from 1 VC to another VC

Comment: I appreciate your response. Thank you.
And in this e.g.:

override func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         didTap? (swiftLang [indexPath.row])
 }

What different action could we use with this closure? Could I make a binding with a completion handler?

Comment: What do you mean by “what different action could we use with this closure”? This closure, i.e. anonymous function, would define functionality and do something on the data inserted into the closure. In your case, it takes in a string and returns void. Thus, we’d do something to that string within the closure, i.e. create an alert and display it to the user. I’m not sure what we would be binding? Maybe clarification on that?

Comment: I am learning and with a little difficulty understanding this way of using closures. I found it a little confusing. The point is that I would like to understand why the usage it in this way as demonstrated on e.g. Thank you for another answer. It helps me a lot to understand.

Comment: I would recommend looking into why Swift is not traditional OOP and is more Protocol based programming. It might help concrete these small things

Comment: Excellent tip. I will do that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case the `didTap` is internal (not private) which means that it can be set from outside of the view controller. You can compare it to a delegate which also can be set from outside or injected into a view controller. The whole purpose of this is to delegate a task. In your case the tap on a cell is delegated.

See it like that: This makes the view controller more dumb and the less responsibilities a it has the leaner, more testable and easier to understand it is.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It is helping me to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The "motivation", quite simply, is when a property needs to be a verb rather than a noun (or an adjective).

Consider a totally independent UIButton. It is its own target and contains its own action. But that means it must have a property saying what *to do* when the button is pressed.

What type would that property be? It would be a `() -> ()` — a function. And the action method would *call* that property to make that function happen.

So for example:

```
class SelfContainedButton : UIButton {
    var whatToDo: (()->())
    init(whatToDo: @escaping ()->()) {
        self.whatToDo = whatToDo
        super.init(frame:.zero)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    @objc func doAction(_ sender:Any) {
        self.whatToDo()
    }
    required init(coder:NSCoder) {
        fatalError("no coder init")
    }
}
```

Notice the type of `whatToDo`. It is a function, so that we can *assign* to this self-contained button the *function* it should call whenever it is later tapped.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let rect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 20)
        let b = SelfContainedButton() {
            print("howdy")
        }
        b.frame = rect
        b.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
        b.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        b.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
        b.sizeToFit()
        self.view.addSubview(b)
    }
}
```

Run the code. Tap the button. What happens? Now think about *how* that happened.

Comment: Thank you! This help out a lot with my learning.

Comment: Added a further code example to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks for example, Matt! This help me out. Great tip with the button usages